# PowerShell - Distinct values in column of multiple files

Tags: powershell, count, unique, streamreader, import-csv

I'm trying to read in a set of `|` pipe-delimited text files and get the number of unique values in a certain column for each file, as well as the number of rows in the file. I tried using `Import-CSV` but it was taking hours and using up a lot of memory. The files can range from 20MB to 500MB, 10-15 files.

Would using a stream reader be faster? How would I count up the unique values?

```
Get-ChildItem .\*filtered.txt -Name  | 
ForEach-Object {
    if($dayofweek -eq 1) {
        $importFile = Import-Csv $_ -Delimiter '|'
    } else {
        $importFile = Import-Csv $_ -Delimiter '|' -Header @("a", "Order-ID", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")
    }
    $numRows = $importFile | Measure-Object | Select-Object -expand count
    $numUniqueOrderID = $importFile | Select Order-ID -Unique
    echo "Filename: $_ `t Rows: $numRows `t"
    echo "Unique Order-IDs"
    $numUniqueOrderID
    echo `n
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Streamreader would be zillion times faster. So the idea would be to get the data into the memory with Streamreader and then do `$data = ConvertFrom-Csv -InputObject $result`. And after that you would do something like `Sort-Object -unique` or add a `-Property` to sort by.

Edit: Alternatively, if you don't want to mess with Streamreader, you could use `$content = Get-Content $file -ReadCount 0`, yeah, you would lose like 0.01% of effectiveness, but why bother.

Answer (score 0):

without certainty

```
Get-ChildItem .\*filtered.txt -File   | 
% {
    if($dayofweek -eq 1) 
     {$numUniqueOrderID = (Import-Csv $_.FullName -Delimiter '|' | Select Order-ID -Unique).Count} 
    else 
     {$numUniqueOrderID = (Import-Csv $_.FullName -Delimiter '|' -Header "a", "Order-ID", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" | Select Order-ID -Unique).Count}

    $numRows = (gc $_.FullName  -ReadCount 0).Count
    write-host ("Filename: {0}`t Rows : {1}`nUnique Order-IDs : {2}`n" -f $_, $numRows, $numUniqueOrderID)   
  }
```